# Exception after update Fabric JS version from 1.4.0 to 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I just update my **FabricJS** plugin from **1.4.0** to **3.0.0** but i now have this exception ***Uncaught TypeError: group.getWidth is not a function***. This is the snippet of where the error is coming from 
`group.left = group.getWidth() / 2 + transX * scale;` Anyone has an idea how to fix it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method was named to `getScaledWidth()`

Ref: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#getScaledWidth

You can try to search in the latest version of fabric js documents.